# Regex that includes possibility of new lines between HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I have this pattern:
`/(\<iframe)(.*?)src="(.*?)(something)(.*?)"((\n|.)*?)(<\/iframe>)/`
With a subject of something like this:

```
<p><iframe src="blah.something.blah">words<br />
<span>tags</span><br />
<span>tags</span><br />
<span itemprop="description" content=""></span><br />
<span itemprop="duration" content="1818"></span><br />
</iframe></p>
```

And while it works while testing in JS on regexr.com, it fails on PHP.
If I remove the newlines and then switch the `((\n|.)*?)` to `(.*?)` it works fine, but that is not good enough.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: "it fails on PHP" - how did you define that? I've just tested your regex, it works well

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest returns false. doesn't match.

Comment: add your current php code into question, let's see

Comment: try adding `/ms` modifiers to enable multiline and allow `.` to match newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, “You should never parse HTML with regex”.

Use a Parser instead: it's not too hard and it gives you a lot of possibilities.

See these examples with your HTML sample using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`:

First, init `DOMDocument`, load HTML and init `DOMXPath`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
```

To retrieve all `<iframe>` `src`attributes:

```
$iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );
foreach( $iframes as $iframe )
{
    echo $iframe->getAttribute( 'src' ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

To retrieve “1818” from `itemprop` attribute `duration`:

```
$duration = $xpath->query( '//span[@itemprop="duration"]/@content' );
echo $duration->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
```

The above xPath pattern means:

```
//                      Selects following pattern no matter where they are in the document
span                    with tag = 'span'
[@itemprop="duration"]  with attribute 'itemprop' = 'duration'
/@content               (get) attribute 'content'
```

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- Read more about [xPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: I will give this a shot and report back.